# Finding Pair sum in O(nlogn) time. Please do not tell me hashmap solution of O(n) time

Tags: c++, time-complexity

Please give solution in O(nlogn) time. Given a random integer array `A` and a number `x`. Find and print the pair of elements in the array which sum to `x`. Array might contain duplicate elements.

Sample Input:

n=9

array elements: 1 3 6 2 5 4 3 2 4

x=7

Sample Output:

1 6

3 4

3 4

2 5

2 5

3 4

3 4

Here is my solution which only works for unique elements:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
void pairSum(int input[], int size, int x) {
  sort(input, input + size);
  int i = 0, j = size - 1, min = 0, max = 0;
  while (i < j) {
    if ((input[i] + input[j]) > x) {
      j--;
    } else if ((input[i] + input[j]) < x) {
      i++;
    } else {
      if (input[i] > input[j]) {
        min = input[i];
        max = input[j];
        i++, j--;
      } else {
        min = input[i];
        max = input[j];
        i++, j--;
      }
      cout << min << " " << max << endl;
    }
  }
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question yet. (You should be able to adapt your solution to support duplicates.)

Comment: if you want unique pairs just remove the duplicates from sorted array in O(n).

Comment: algorithms don't just pop out of nothingness, especially optimised ones.

Comment: Sample Input:
9
1 3 6 2 5 4 3 2 4
7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want the duplicates to be printed as well. That requires just a small change to your original algorithm. It's marked with a comment:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

template<typename It, typename value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type>
void pairSum(It begin, It end, const value_type& x) {
    if(begin == end) return;

    std::sort(begin, end);
    std::advance(end, -1);
    while(begin < end) {
        if(x < *begin + *end) {
            std::advance(end, -1);
        } else if(*begin + *end < x) {
            std::advance(begin, 1);
        } else {
            std::cout << *begin << " + " << *end << " = " << x << '\n';

            // Only step one iterator. If the next value is the same as the currect,
            // step that iterator.
            if(*begin == *std::next(begin, 1)) std::advance(begin, 1);
            else std::advance(end, -1);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{9, 1, 3, 6, 2, 5, 4, 3, 2, 4, 7};
    pairSum(v.begin(), v.end(), 10);
}
```

Output

```
1 + 9 = 10
3 + 7 = 10
3 + 7 = 10
4 + 6 = 10
4 + 6 = 10
```

Comment: I don't want to use vector. Please help me solve it using array only

Comment: @TaslimArif The `pairSum()` function works with iterators, so it works with using arrays too. `int a[]{9, 1, 3, 6, 2, 5, 4, 3, 2, 4, 7};  pairSum(std::begin(a), std::end(a), 10);`  or `pairSum(a, a+std::size(a), 10);`